# Homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ with itself

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a problem from Munkres' book Topology.:

> > Given sequences $(a_{1},a_{2},\dots)$ and $(b_{1},b_{2},\dots)$ of real numbers with $a_{i}>0$ for all $i$, define $h\colon \mathbb{R}^{\omega}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ by the equation
> > \begin{align*}
> >     h((x_{1},x_{2},\dots)) = (a_{1}x_{1} + b_{1}, a_{2}x_{2} + b_{2},\dots ).
> >    \end{align*}
> > Show that if $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is given the product topology, $h$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ with itself. What happens if $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is given the box topology?

I have already proved that $h$ is bijective, here is my attempt of continuity:

Let's verify that $h$ and $h^{-1}$ are continuous: let $h_{k}\colon \mathbb{R}^{\omega}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{k}$ be given by
\begin{align*}
   h_{k}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots) = a_{k}x_{k}+b_{k},
  \end{align*}
and proof that this function is continuous. Let $(\alpha,\beta)$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}_{k}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in h_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$. We'll show that $h_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$ is open. Consider de basis element of the product topology:
\begin{align*}
   \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}}, \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\right).
  \end{align*}
First, note that since $h_{k}(\mathbf{x})\in (\alpha,\beta)$, i.e., $a_{k}x_{k}+b_{k}\in (\alpha,\beta)$, then:
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}} < x_{k} < \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\;\; \text{ i.e, } \;\; x_{k} \in \left(\frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}}, \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\right), 
  \end{align*}
which implies that
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf{x}\in \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}}, \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\right).
  \end{align*}
Now, if $\mathbf{y} \in \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}}, \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\right)$, then
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}} < y_{k} < \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\;\; \text{ which gives }\;\; a_{k}y_{k}+b_{k}\in (\alpha,\beta),
  \end{align*}
i.e., $\mathbf{y}\in h_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$, so $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\alpha-b_{k}}{a_{k}}, \frac{\beta - b_{k}}{a_{k}}\right)\subseteq h_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$. We conclude that $h_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$ is open and this yields that $h_{k}$ is continuous. Since every $h_{k}$ is continuous then $h$ es continous.

Now, the inverse map of $h$ is $h^{-1}\colon \mathbb{R}^{\omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\omega}$, where
\begin{align*}
   h^{-1}(\mathbf{x}) = \left(\frac{x_{1}-b_{1}}{a_{1}}, \frac{x_{2}-b_{2}}{a_{2}}, \dots \right). 
  \end{align*}
Let $g_{k}\colon \mathbb{R}^{\omega} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{k}$ be given by $g_{k}(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{x_{k}-b_{k}}{a_{k}}$. Let $(\alpha,\beta)$ be an interval of $\mathbb{R}_{k}$ and $\mathbf{x}\in g_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$. Consider the basis element of the product topology:
\begin{align*}
   \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{k}\alpha + b_{k}, a_{k}\beta + b_{k}\right).
  \end{align*}
Since $g_{k}(\mathbf{x})\in (\alpha,\beta)$, then
\begin{align*}
   \alpha a_{k} + b_{k}<x_{k}<\beta a_{k} + b_{k}, \;\; \text{ i.e., }\;\; x_{k}\in \left(\alpha a_{k} + b_{k}, \beta a_{k} + b_{k}\right). 
  \end{align*}
This yields that $\mathbf{x}\in \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{k}\alpha + b_{k}, a_{k}\beta + b_{k}\right)$. Similarly with $h$ we get the following inclusion: $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(a_{k}\alpha + b_{k}, a_{k}\beta + b_{k}\right)\subseteq g_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$ and so $g_{k}^{-1}(\alpha,\beta)$ is open and thus $g_{k}$ is continuous. Since every $g_{k}$ is continuous, then $h^{-1}$ is also continuous. This completes the proof.

Proving that each component function is continuous only works if $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is given the product topology, so this proof would not work in the case of the box topology.

Comment: Your “basis element” isn’t a basis element. Also, given that you have a fixed $k,$ you shouldn’t also write $\prod_k.$ That can all be fixed.  $$h_k^{-1}((\alpha,\beta))=\prod_{i} U_i,$$ where $U_i=\mathbb R$  when $i\neq k$ and $U_k=…$

Comment: Also, $\mathbb R^{\omega}$ often means the subspace of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ which consists of sequences $(a_i)$ where all but finitely many $a_i$ are zero. If that is what is meant here, you have to consider that.

Comment: Hint: use that for any space $Y$, any function $f : Y\to \Bbb R^\omega$ is continuous (for the product topology) iff for all $n \in \omega$ we have that $p_n \circ f:Y \to \Bbb R$ is continuous. This can be applied to both $h$ and $h^{-1}$…